# How often does angular js poll functions passed under $watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

If I were to create a `$watch` expression like:

```
         $scope.$watch(function(){
              return(MyDataStore.someInstanceVariable);}
          , function(newVal, oldVal){
               $scope.scopeVariable = newVal;}
          , true)
```

How often would this function execute? How often would it poll the data store? Just how (in)efficient is this approach?

Comment: It would poll the data store at least as many times as there are $digest loops.  Read [Databinding in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the angularjs docs:

The watchExpression is called on every call to $digest() and should return the value which will be watched. (Since $digest() reruns when it detects changes the watchExpression can execute multiple times per $digest() and should be idempotent.)

See the docs at: [Angularjs Watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)